# Formatted String Literals in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

While writing a module in Python 2.7 I had the need of a way for doing

```
name = "Rodrigo"
age = 34
print f"Hello {name}, your age is {age}".format()
```

although I know I could just do:

```
print "Hello {name}, your age is {age}".format(name=name, age=age)
```

`format()` would look in the scope for variables `name` and `age`, cast them to a string (if possible) and paste into the message. I've found that this is already implemented in Python 3.6+, called *[Formatted String Literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498)*. So, I was wondering (couldn't find it googling) if anyone has made an approach to something similar for Python 2.7

Comment: AFAIK, this is still a Python 3.6 and greater feature only.

Comment: A rather hacky version is to use `.format(dict(globals(), **locals()))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the **hackish** way of doing things by combining the builtin `locals` function and the `format` method on the string:

```
foo = "asd"
bar = "ghi"

print("{foo} and {bar}".format(**locals())
```

Comment: Note that this still doesn't cover the full functionality of Python 3.6 _f-strings_. You can execute actual Python expressions inside of them.

Comment: i don't think the author's purpose was to get an exact equivalent, but rather to reproduce a know functionality...

Comment: I understand what @ChristianDean says, but agree with omu_negru. I just want to reproduce the functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation that automatically inserts variables. Note that it doesn't support any of the fancier features python 3 f-strings have (like attribute access):

```
import inspect

def fformat(string):
    caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    names = dict(caller_frame.f_globals, **caller_frame.f_locals)
    del caller_frame
    return string.format(**names)
```

```
a = 1
foo = 'bar'
print fformat('hello {a} {foo}')
# output: "hello 1 bar"
```